# AWS CLI Configure Profile parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Calling the following AWS CLI SDK command triggers the shell prompting for a series of values:

```
$ aws configure --profile profilename
```

$ AWS Access Key ID [None]:
etc....

Is there any way to specify the parameters in line? E.g.

```
$ aws configure --profile profilename --access-key=foo --access-secret=goo --region=bar
```

Thanx in adv,
Michael McD

Comment: Four years later and I still would like to be able to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of. You can't do them all at once (`aws configure help` will show you there are no such options), but can do them one at a time.

From `aws configure set help`:

> Given an empty config file, the following commands:
>
> ```
> $ aws configure set aws_access_key_id default_access_key
> $ aws configure set aws_secret_access_key default_secret_key
> $ aws configure set default.region us-west-2
> $ aws configure set default.ca_bundle /path/to/ca-bundle.pem
> $ aws configure set region us-west-1 --profile testing
> $ aws configure set profile.testing2.region eu-west-1
> $ aws configure set preview.cloudsearch true
> ```
>
> will produce the following config file:
>
> ```
> [default]
> region = us-west-2
> ca_bundle = /path/to/ca-bundle.pem
>
> [profile testing]
> region = us-west-1
>
> [profile testing2]
> region = eu-west-1
>
> [preview]
> cloudsearch = true
> ```
>
> and the following ~/.aws/credentials file:
>
> ```
> [default]
> aws_access_key_id = default_access_key
> aws_secret_access_key = default_secret_key
> ```

Note that you could also set the credentials temporarily as environment variables when running other `aws` commands. If that's interesting to you, [see the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html). You can't just set them and run `aws configure --profile profilename` though -- this will still prompt you.